# Mod Rewrite and search query string

Tags: php, forms, input, request, url-rewriting

To search something, user need to use following URL:

```
http://.../results/query/something
```

I got my text input, in which user type the string to be posted, but it looks then following:

```
http://.../results/query/?query=something
```

I've tried to change the 'post method' type, but doesn't bring any good results. How can I do that, so it'll look like that?

```
http://.../results/query/something
```

Comment: You can't do that with PHP (unless you wanna redirect) JS is perfect for that purpose.

Comment: Um, fine, but how can I do that then using JS?

Comment: Posted a sample as an answer, OFC change "yourdomain" to your domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form id="myform" method="post" action="/">
<input type="text" id="query" name="query" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" onclick="return go();" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function go(){
    var query = document.getElementById('query').value;
    document.getElementById('myform').action = 'http://yourdomain/results/query/'+query;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer:

- Use `method="post"`
- Construct the URL with PHP after the form is posted, using `urlencode()` and any other appropriate sanitization on the value.
- Redirect to the page you want.

```
 $query = isset($_POST['query']) ? urlencode($_POST['query']) : '';
 header("Location: results/query/$query");
```